# Change Task triggering but not reflecting the field values on OIM process Form

Tags: identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

When I am changing any attributes of user from User Profile its changing those attributes in OIM and target also. The change Tasks are getting called when checked in the Resource History, but the updated data is not shown in the OIM Process Form.

What could be the cause of the same? and what could be the possible solution? Where should I debug for it?

Answer (score 0):

Some things to double check

1. In the process form, does the Change Task exist, does it simply copy the user attribute to the process data field?
2. Does the change task exist in the Lookup.USR_PROCESS_TRIGGERS table?
3. Is there an XX Updated task that was triggered?  how was that triggered, and does the updated task pull the data from the user definition or the process form?
4. Here is some SQL to get Resource history

   `-- Grabs Resource History by ORC_KEY
   SELECT osi.sch_key
   , osi.orc_key
   , osi.mil_key
   , to_char(osi.osi_assigned_date,'dd-mon-rrrr hh24:mi:ss') as OSI_ASSIGNED_DATE
   , to_char(OSI.OSI_UPDATE,'dd-mon-rrrr hh24:mi:ss') as OSI_UPDATED
   , osi.rsc_key, sch.sch_status, sch.sch_data, mil.mil_name, SCH.sch_update
   , to_char(sysdate,'dd-mon-rrrr hh24:mi:ss') as NOW
   FROM osi, sch, mil
   WHERE osi.sch_key = sch.sch_key 
   AND osi.mil_key = mil.mil_key 
   AND osi.orc_key in ('<PUT_ORC_KEY_HERE>')
   ORDER BY sch.sch_update DESC;`

Comment: This helped me debug the issue. Actually there are change task for this OOTB connector but its firing changes directly to the target and process form is not getting updated values. To resolve this issue I have  created one process task which will do the change task activity and add it in the `responses --> Under Task to generate`